# Can someone access my computer after I clicked a Grabify link?

Tags: ip

I accidentally clicked a grabify link and the person said that he got my IP address, he said that he can see through my camera and spy on my online activity and can take my data and files from my computer, is this true? Sorry, this is my first time encountering this.